# Making cake and added oil at end instead of at the beginning

Tags: cake, oil

I forgot to add the oil at the beginning of my zucchini cake and had to add it at the end, after all the flour was in.  So I had to beat it in a little.  Do you think it will still turn out?

Comment: Welcome to the site! There's no way to answer this without knowing the complete recipe and method you are *supposed* to follow. Please edit and add these details.

Comment: I'm guessing you've baked it by now.  How'd it turn out?

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while since I've done it (mine were mostly with muffins, although I might've done it with some zucchini brownies this past spring), but I want to say it'll come out, but it might be different.

You'll have developed more gluten, as oil coating the flour prevents the water from getting to it as quickly.  And there's the extra beating to get it all in there.  So it probably won't come out as light as you were hoping.

But I find zucchini bread & cake recipes to be highly variable anyway -- as how much liquid you squeeze out of it (and by extension, how finely you grate it), has a huge impact on the final result.